# Cell.CellReference возвращает null

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Почему CellReference return null
Как избежать?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
{            
   WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
   WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
   SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
   foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
   {
      DataRow rs = pt.ListImport.NewRow();
      if (nrow > 0)
      {
         foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
         {
            if (c.CellReference == null) 
                continue;
            string s = c.CellValue.InnerTex;
         }
      }   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае это решило вопрос

```
foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
{
   if (r.RowIndex > 2)
   {
      int nc = 0;
      foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.CellReference))
           nc = GetNumByRef(c.CellReference);
        else
           nc++;
        if (c.CellValue == null)
        {
           continue;
        }
        string s = c.CellValue.InnerTex
        //...  
     }
}
private int GetNumByRef(string cellReference)
{
// функция из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875815/get-the-column-index-of-a-cell-in-excel-using-openxml-c-sharp
   string columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]",  string.Empty);
   int columnNumber = -1;
   int mulitplier = 1;
   foreach (char c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse())
   {
      columnNumber += mulitplier * ((int)c - 64);
      mulitplier = mulitplier * 26;
   }
   return columnNumber + 1;
}
```